# SQL search articles by tag when the tag is formatted and retrieved from the url

Tags: php, mysql

How do I write a (MySQL) query to find rows where a column contains value obtained from a url query string?

I can do `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE %tag%`, which is fine when the tag is a single word. However I want to support tags made up of multiple words.

To make my URLs nice I'm stripping out certain characters and replacing spaces with dashes. For example a tag like "Stack Overflow" would become "stack-overflow" when retrieved from the URL as a query string.

It would also be nice to support tags with punctuation like "17/18" which would get converted to "17-18", or "how's it going?" which would get converted to "how-s-it-going", or "Movie 2: The revenge" which would get converted to "movie-2-the-revenge".

I can't figure a way to do it. Will I need something like a permalink column for my tags and use that to store the url converted tag?

Comment: yes - use a permalink coloumn or a own table. use mod_rewrite to redirect to your controller and read the $_GET from it.. or requested url... check with your database and then load the page you want to deliver to the user

Answer (score 0):

One of possible ways (beside the permalink column for tags) is to have a full-text index on the "column" column and use a full-text search, replacing all dashes to spaces:

```
$search = str_replace('-', ' ', $tag);
$sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(column) AGAINST('$search')";
```

Or, with prepared statement:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(column) AGAINST(?)";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can even try this to get the perfect tag from table attribute if it contain multiple words.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP "[[:<:]]tag[[:>:]]"
```